# CakePHP2.7 Error: FlashComponent could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHPの勉強にCoocbookで進めているのですがユーザーの処理を追加したら下記のエラーが出力されました。CakePHP2.7.3ではFlashComponentが無いのでしょうか？

```
Error: FlashComponent could not be found.


// app/Controller/AppController.php
class AppController extends Controller {
    //...

    public $components = array(
        'Flash',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'posts',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }
    //...
}
```

[参照ソース：Cookbook 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純にあるかないかで言えば存在します。

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/FlashComponent.php

CakePHPのインストールに問題があるのでなければ、ソースが提示されない限り、エラーの具体的な原因は特定しがたいです。

---

#### 追記

提示されたソース自体には特に問題はなさそうに見えます。手元の別プロジェクトで試してみましたが、同様の記述方法で特にエラーは出ていません。
その状況で `FlashComponent could not be found.` ということは、Cakeが該当コンポーネントを見つけられないということですから、インストールに失敗しているかあるいは何か設定に問題がありそうです。

どのようにCakePHPをインストールしたのか、CakePHPおよび当該プロジェクトのディレクトリレイアウトはどうなっているか、`app/Config/core.php` あるいは `app/Config/bootstrap.php` 辺りに何か特殊な設定をしていないか、などといった点に問題が隠れていそうです。

たとえば提示されたソースで`$components`から`'Flash'`だけを外すと、今度は`AuthComponent`が見つからないなどといったエラーになったりしませんか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。ソースを提示させて頂きました。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。
ダウンロード中に問題が発生した可能性があるので再ダウンロードしてみます。
特殊な設定ファイルは更新していません。
'Flash'を外した場合はエラーが出ませんでした。
しかし、Flashを利用している処理が有り、そちらが動作しなくなります。

Comment: 再ダウンロードしたら解決しました。ありがとうございます。